Aggregated rollup in PostgreSQL with avg and sum in different levels?
I have a PostgreSQL query that aggregates data from multiple tables and generates a report. Currently it works perfectly fine and it is quite simple. Here is the query I'm using:
SELECT
  a.name AS account_name,
  c.name AS campaign_name,
  ad.name AS ad_name,
  g.cpm AS cpm,
  SUM(g.impressions) AS impressions,
  SUM(g.clicks) AS clicks,
  SUM(g.conversions) AS conversions,
  SUM(g.impressions) * g.cpm AS cost,
  SUM(g.revenue) AS order_revenue
FROM google_analytics g
JOIN ad ad ON ad.id = g.ad_id
JOIN campaign c ON c.id = ad.campaign_id
JOIN account a ON a.id = c.account_id
WHERE g.created_at >= ? AND g.created_at <= ?
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY 2

And my table schema:
CREATE TABLE public.google_analytics (
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NULL,
  ad_id INTEGER NULL,
  impressions INTEGER NULL,
  clicks INTEGER NULL,
  conversions INTEGER NULL,
  ecpm INTEGER NULL,
  commission SMALLINT NULL,
  revenue INTEGER NULL
);

The current report aggregates data properly with the SUM and GROUP BY clauses, and works as expected. However, the application code extends this report by handling additional calculations and aggregations, such as rollups, averaging certain fields, and building a hierarchical structure.
For example, the application generates a report like this:



account_name
campaign_name
ad_name
cpm
impressions
clicks
conversions
cost
order_revenue




Account A


1.75 CPM
2200
20
2
1.45
$150



Campaign A
Ad 1
1.50 CPM
1000
10
1
0.50
$100



Campaign A
Ad 2
2.00 CPM
1200
10
1
2.40
$50



In this structure:

Impressions, clicks, and revenue are summed
CPM and cost are averaged
The data is grouped hierarchically by account, campaign, and ad

The application code handling these calculations is very large and complex, making it difficult to maintain. I am planning to replace this application logic with a SQL-based solution to simplify maintenance and improve performance.
I have experimented with the ROLLUP and CUBE features in PostgreSQL, and I got excited about the capabilities they offer. These features seem to perform much of the grunt work that the application currently does. My initial results were very promising and I got the very same tree-like structure for summing up all the metrics.
However, I am unsure if PostgreSQL's built-in rollup supports averaging and summing at different levels of the hierarchy. My goal is to use these features to replace the application code and handle the calculations directly within the database.
For instance:

I was unable to calculate the average instead of the sum: how can the rollup use average for a column, and sum for another column? It seems to always sum things
I was unable to calculate the sum of cost, since cost is already a calculated field

In order to contextualize even more, and sake of understanding the tree, this is the final JSON I am planning to generate:
[
  {
    "name": "Account A",
    "impressions": 236797,
    "cpm": 2.48,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Campaign A",
        "impressions": 236797,
        "cpm": 2.48,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Ad 1",
            "impressions": 236797,
            "cpm": 2.48,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]


Please update your post with sample data, the expected/desired output, and the code you have tried. Without the context of source data, the provided output examples are of very limited value. You mention trying CUBE and ROLLUP, but didn't provide the code needed to assess your attempts and offer suggestions.

Use names instead of ordinals for GROUP BY and ORDER BY. The use of ordinals results in fragile queries (changes to the select list can easily break the query) and imposes a higher cognitive load on the reader than does the use of names.


I am unsure if PostgreSQL's built-in rollup supports averaging and summing at different levels of the hierarchy.

It does: there's a grouping function that tells you which "level" you're on, and based on that you can alternate between the AVG and SUM the way you wanted: demo at db<>fiddle
SELECT
  grouping(a.name, c.name, ad.name) as grouping,
  grouping(a.name, c.name, ad.name)::int::bit(3) as grouping_bitmask,
  a.name AS account_name,
  c.name AS campaign_name,
  ad.name AS ad_name,
  CASE grouping(a.name, c.name, ad.name)<>0
    WHEN true THEN AVG(g.cpm)
    ELSE SUM(g.cpm) 
  END AS cpm,
  AVG(g.cpm) AS avg_cpm,
  SUM(g.cpm) AS sum_cpm,
  SUM(g.impressions) AS impressions,
  SUM(g.clicks) AS clicks,
  SUM(g.conversions) AS conversions,
  CASE grouping(a.name, c.name, ad.name)<>0
    WHEN true THEN AVG(g.impressions*g.cpm)
    ELSE SUM(g.impressions*g.cpm)
  END AS cost,
  AVG(g.impressions*g.cpm) AS avg_cost,
  SUM(g.impressions*g.cpm) AS sum_cost,
  SUM(g.revenue) AS order_revenue
FROM google_analytics g
JOIN ad ad ON ad.id = g.ad_id
JOIN campaign c ON c.id = ad.campaign_id
JOIN account a ON a.id = c.account_id
WHERE g.created_at >= (now()-'1 month'::interval) 
  AND g.created_at <= (now()-'2 weeks'::interval) 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(account_name, campaign_name, ad_name)
ORDER BY account_name, campaign_name, ad_name;

The avg_cpm and sum_cpm next to cpm (same for cost) shows you how that case alternates between them on different levels based on the grouping:



grouping
grouping_bitmask
account_name
campaign_name
ad_name
cpm
avg_cpm
sum_cpm
impressions
clicks
conversions
cost
avg_cost
sum_cost
order_revenue




0
000
account_1
campaign_1_account_1
ad_1_campaign_1_account_1
1600
1600.0
1600
7
19
1
11200
11200.0
11200
1000


1
001
account_1
campaign_1_account_1
null
1600.0
1600.0
1600
7
19
1
11200.0
11200.0
11200
1000


0
000
account_1
campaign_2_account_1
ad_1_campaign_2_account_1
800
800.0
800
15
11
19
12000
12000.0
12000
300


0
000
account_1
campaign_2_account_1
ad_2_campaign_2_account_1
400
400.0
400
0
5
13
0
0.00000
0
200


1
001
account_1
campaign_2_account_1
null
600.0
600.0
1200
15
16
32
6000.0
6000.0
12000
500


3
011
account_1
null
null
933.33
933.33
2800
22
35
33
7733.33
7733.33
23200
1500


0
000
account_2
campaign_2_account_2
ad_1_campaign_2_account_2
2500
2500.0
2500
18
19
7
45000
45000.0
45000
400


1
001
account_2
campaign_2_account_2
null
2500.0
2500.0
2500
18
19
7
45000.0
45000.0
45000
400


3
011
account_2
null
null
2500.0
2500.0
2500
18
19
7
45000.0
45000.0
45000
400


7
111
null
null
null
1325.0
1325.0
5300
40
54
40
17050.0
17050.0
68200
1900



That being said, it seems that you could just plug in a /count(*) to your SUMs: in individual rows, that'll be 1, so you'll keep getting the sum. On higher levels, it'll jump up to how many rows got aggregated, and SUM divided by COUNT will result in an AVG:
SELECT
  a.name AS account_name,
  c.name AS campaign_name,
  ad.name AS ad_name,
  SUM(g.cpm)/count(*) AS cpm,
  SUM(g.impressions) AS impressions,
  SUM(g.clicks) AS clicks,
  SUM(g.conversions) AS conversions,
  SUM(g.impressions*g.cpm)/count(*) AS cost,
  SUM(g.revenue) AS order_revenue
FROM google_analytics g
JOIN ad ad ON ad.id = g.ad_id
JOIN campaign c ON c.id = ad.campaign_id
JOIN account a ON a.id = c.account_id
WHERE g.created_at >= (now()-'1 month'::interval) 
  AND g.created_at <= (now()-'2 weeks'::interval) 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(account_name, campaign_name, ad_name)
ORDER BY account_name, campaign_name, ad_name;

